# MySQL table data dir is bigger than size calculate from information_schema.tables

Tags: mysql, linux

Is it valid that the size of my table's data dir in MySQL 5.6 on Linux machine is much biggern than the size that I'm getting from information_schema.tables query?

The size in the file system (/data/) is 11G,

While the following query returns 5G

```
SELECT sum(ROUND(((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH ) / 1024 / 1024),2)) AS size FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema='my-table-name
```

Am I missing something?

---

```
total          | free         | data          | index_data   |
 4597.85937500 | 613.00000000 | 4089.40625000 | 508.45312500 |
```

Comment: see answer , return the output

Answer (score 0):

**Here is script i use to find my database size :**

```
SELECT 
table_schema "DB Name",  
Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB"  FROM 
information_schema.tables  where table_schema ='schema name' ;
```

---

**Run this query and show us the output :**

```
select (sum(data_length) + sum(INDEX_LENGTH))/ 1024 / 1024 as total, 
    sum(data_free)/ 1024 / 1024  as free ,
    sum(data_length)/ 1024 / 1024 as data, 
    sum(INDEX_LENGTH/ 1024 / 1024) as index_data 
    from information_schema.tables t
    where t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema name';
```

Comment: +---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| total         | free         | data          | index_data   |
+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| 4597.85937500 | 613.00000000 | 4089.40625000 | 508.45312500 |
+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+